# Php mysql .net replace strings in application

Tags: php, mysql, .net

hi i was wondering if there is any ways at all to finish a build on an application to insert strings etc.

i have seen some example in my life when i had it on my hard drive, but i can't seem to find it, and was wondering if any of you guys out there has some tips or perhaps an open source?

thanks in advance.

i have been googling around, can't seem to find any examples unless i was looking at someone who made it already.

i have no clue if it can be some settings in mysql that also needs for the build to work, but i am clueless so im turning to you guys.

Comment: What are you doing??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i tried to explain as much as possible, what im looking to do is make a c# application is visual studio then have strings that are emtpy.
on the php side i want to insert the strings that are empty.